# Mongoose nested object not updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Summary**

I'm doing a findOneAndUpdate and trying to update a nested object.  I can find the document but the field I'm trying to update is not being updated. I've included all of the relevant code below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Mongoose Model**

```
const instantCompCompetitors = {
  userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", require: true },
  startingLifeTimeStats: { type: statsFieldsSchema, require: true },
  stats: { type: String, require: true },
  rank: { type: Number, require: false }
};

const instantCompSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", require: true },
  compName: { type: String, require: true },
  startDate: { type: Date, require: true },
  endDate: { type: Date, require: false }, //changed this to false bc we wont have end date  when competition starts
  inProgress: { type: Boolean, require: true, default: true }, //TODO should I have the default here or just set it to true?  Probably easier to have default and then not set it but that seems like may cause errors
  competitors: [instantCompCompetitors]
});
```

**findOneAndUpdate**

```
 const updatedComp = await InstantComp.findOneAndUpdate(
                {
                  _id: compId,
                  "competitors.userId": userObj._id,
                  inProgress: true
                },
                { $set: { "competitors.stats": "testing" } },
                { new: true }
              );
```

**Error**

MongoError: Cannot create field 'stats' in element

**What I've tried**

I've tried changing $set to push since the nested object is inside an array however that is also not working.

Comment: Can you provide your sample documents, I would say to check on using $ operator

Comment: Good call, I changed ""competitors.stats" to "competitors.$.stats" and it's working perfectly now.  Thanks for your help!  I forgot I needed the $ when the object is inside of an array

Comment: Good that you've solved it, but just go through the mongoDB documentation of $, $[<identifier>] and $[], as $ would modify the first found element in the array, test your update queries to check if correct competitors document is being updated and please make changes if needed !!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it withs ome help from @srinivasy!

**Solution**
"competitors.stats" in findOneAndUpdate should be "competitors.$.stats".  The $ should be included in the path for the element you want to update when that element is inside of an array.  Competitors is an array which is why $ is necessary.